# How to inject @PersistenceContext in DAO generated by Hibernate3-maven-plugin

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I wanna create a Java Application based on **Hibernate-3** and **Spring Framework**. To get the process easy I found **hibernate3-maven-plugin** that is able to perform reverse-engineering of the existing database.
Here there's example of POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>hbm2java</name>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
            </component>
            <component>
                <name>hbm2dao</name>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
            </component>
        </components>
        <componentProperties>
            <revengfile>/src/main/resources/model.reveng.xml</revengfile>
            <propertyfile>/src/main/resources/hibernate.properties</propertyfile>
            <jdk5>true</jdk5>
            <ejb3>true</ejb3>
        </componentProperties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                <goal>hbm2dao</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then I set up the context of Spring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="gomer" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManager" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory" factory-method="createEntityManager"/>

        <bean id="user" class="ru.tomtrix.first.db.UserHome">
            <property name="entityManager" ref="entityManager"/>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

It perfectly generates an Entity file and a DAO file except the following. In DAO file there's a EntityManager:

```
@Stateless
public class UserHome {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserHome.class);

    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;
```

... and this field hasn't got a setter! Eventually Spring throws the exception:

```
Invalid property 'entityManager' of bean class [ru.tomtrix.first.db.UserHome]: Bean property 'entityManager' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Of course it's not a good practice to write the setter manually. I think there is a way to inject a manager properly.
So how to do it without rewriting the generated file?

Corresponding information:
1) I'd like to create a stand alone application (and possibly run it in an Application Server like Tomcat)
2) model.reveng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table-filter match-name=".*" package="ru.tomtrix.first.db"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

3) persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="gomer" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="1234"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are missing a part of the configuration. You need to tell Spring that you want to (also) use annotations for configuration. For this add the `<context:annotation-config />` to your configuration and remove the setting of the `entityManager`

Next to that remove the calling of the factory method spring will handle all that for you.

Added tip use the version-less schemas insead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="gomer" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="user" class="ru.tomtrix.first.db.UserHome" />

</beans>
```

Your code might be problematic when you deploy it to a fullblown app server and you might run into issues with Spring and the EJB container competing over control of the beans. The hibernate plugin generates `@Stateless` session beans which in general will be picked up by the app. server (depending on which one you use).

Comment: This config looks much better to work properly but the application throws exception: "**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata: method <init>()V not found**" at the line: `BeanFactory factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("trix.xml");`  Is my approach to get a context wrong?

Comment: Oh... It turned out that **Spring.context** and **Spring.orm** had the different versions in POM. So the problem is almost solved. Could you please explain how to work with transactions? As far as I understood the DAO's methods must be provided with @Transactional, but they're still autogenerated!

Comment: I finally found the answer in documentation, section [14.7 Transaction Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch14s07.html)  Thank you, M. Deinum